# scope issue in javascript between two Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, xlsx-populate

i have try to get the excel sheet using xlsx-populate so i am trying to get the values from mailEvents collections so i can add or pass the value in the init Collection function.if i have solved this issue then my problem regarding excel is also solved.
in this problem i want to access the topHeader var in init collection.
here in arr2 there is the values in this form `['open','processed']`

```
const completeReport = (startTime,endTime) => {
    serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");
    let getDocs = serverRef
      .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
      .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot) {
          let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          let arr1 = ["email", "reportName", "office"];
          let arr2 = docs.map(a => a.event);

          let topHeader = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];
        }
      });
      let query = db.collection("inits");
      let queryData = query
        .where("report", "in", ["payroll", "footprints"])

        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          if (querySnapshot) {
            let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            console.log(topHeader)
          }
        });
}
```

so i want the output in this form

```
["email", "reportName", "office",'open','processed']
```

Comment: let has a block scope. Define a global variable instead

Comment: Not quite global, but move the `let` declarations to the second line right before the `serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");` line.  Leave the assignments where they are.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher can you please explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, since it may take some time to return. Instead of waiting for the data to return, your main code continues to execute straight away. Then when the data is available, your `then()` callback is called with that data.

This means that any code that needs access to the data from Firestore must be inside the `then()` callback, or be called from there.

For example:

```
const completeReport = (startTime,endTime) => {
    serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");
    let getDocs = serverRef
      .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
      .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot) {
          let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          let arr1 = ["email", "reportName", "office"];
          let arr2 = docs.map(a => a.event);

          let topHeader = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];

          let query = db.collection("inits");
          let queryData = serverRef
            .where("report", "in", ["payroll", "footprints"])
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
              if (querySnapshot) {
                let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                console.log(topHeader)
              }
            });
        }
      });
}
```

---

There are some alternatives, especially when you're willing to use more modern JavaScript constructs. The simplest approach is to use the `async` /  `await` keywords, which wrap the above in some nice syntactic sugar that reads more normal for most developers.

The above code would become this when you apply `async` / `await`:

```
const completeReport = async (startTime,endTime) => {
    serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");
    let querySnapshot = await serverRef
      .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
      .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
      .get();
    if (querySnapshot) {
      let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      let arr1 = ["email", "reportName", "office"];
      let arr2 = docs.map(a => a.event);

      let topHeader = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];

      let query = db.collection("inits");
      querySnapshot = await serverRef
        .where("report", "in", ["payroll", "footprints"])
        .get();
      if (querySnapshot) {
        let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(topHeader)
      }
    }
}
```

The biggest changes here are:

- The `async` marker on the `completeReport` function, since the caller needs to be aware that this function may now return a promise/exhibit async behavior.
- The `await` keywords on the two `get()` calls, which mean you don't need a `then` block anymore.
- The reduced indentation, especially when compared to the first snippet in my answer.

One of the things to always realize when using this approach is that the calls are still asynchronous. While the use of `async` / `await` makes the code easier to read, it doesn't change the actual behavior of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Since let has block scope it wont be accessible outside.

Would recommend you to declare a variable with `var` and just assign it later.

Hope this helps!

```
const completeReport = () => {
    let serverRef = db.collection("MailEvents");
    var topHeader; 
    let getDocs = serverRef
      .where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)
      .where("timestamp", "<=", endTime)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot) {
          let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          let arr1 = ["email", "reportName", "office"];
          let arr2 = docs.map(a => a.event);

          topHeader = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))]; //assign value
        }
      });
      serverRef = db.collection("inits");
      let queryData = serverRef
        .where("report", "in", ["payroll", "footprints"])

        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          if (querySnapshot) {
            let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            console.log(topHeader)
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: You need `let` in front of `serverRef` there.

Comment: it prints undefined

Comment: @Amar - there was a typo in my code-  changed  var topheader to topHeader. Please cross check

Comment: @MonicaAcha i have tried in my main code but it doesn't work it print undefined

Comment: @Amar Can you post the error log that shows on console

Comment: @MonicaAcha i am running in node enviornment and it only shows undefined.